# m3u8 + 404 + ios Safari = annoying popup: "The requested URL was not found on this server"

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, html5-video, http-status-code-404

**HTML Video tag**

if you load  m3u8, which is 404 (file not found), on ios Safari( ipad )

annoying popup will be resulted:

> "The requested URL was not found on this server"

Is there a way to handle this error, so that pop up won't show.

Comment: interesting thing is, if the file ISN'T 'm3u8', there won't be an error.

Answer (score 2):

First of all [the HTML 5 Video tag only supports a dedicated amount of media formats,](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats).

---

Though "m3u" and "m3u8" files are the basis for the HTTP Live Streaming format used by Apple to stream video to iOS devices. So just in case that your ipad actually can interpret your m3u8 file, there might totally be another problem:

m3u / m3u8 files are only playlist files which contain links to the real media files, so you check out the content of your m3u8 files. I'd strongly advise to use absolute paths in that file instead of relative paths. And make sure that those files are accessible by your device.

Instead of:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:123,Some Fancy Video
Some Fancy Video.mp4
```

it should look similar to this:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:123,Some Fancy Video
http://www.example.com/Some Fancy Video.mp4
```

Comment: first of all, iPad actually can interpret m3u8 file.
Thanks for the reminder, yet you advice only apply to the playlist items. the case here is the m3u8 itself got 404 response.

Comment: So what happens when you open your m3u8 file directly on your device, do you get the same 404? Have you checked the server logs what was requested when the 404 came in?

Comment: 404, of coz. 
What was requested isn't the issue here, is there a way to properly handle the 404 in video tag, so that the annoying msg box won't come up.

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar error today and problem was in configuration Nginx server. We check the header `HTTP_ORIGIN` - if origin header (domain) in list then give access else return 404. But iPhone not present it header.

For check access execure command:

```
curl -I <doman.test>
```

If response see:

```
HTTP/2 200
```

all right!

And yes,

Checked on:

- IOS 12
- android 10